# C# event deadlocks

Tags: c#

I got this:

```
object locker = new object(); // EDIT: sorry, omitted for simplicity. lock(this) is not the source of the problem.
private Something property;
public event SomethingHandler PropertyChanged;

public Something Property
{
    get {
        lock (locker) {
            return property;
        }
    }

    set {
        lock (locker) {
            property = value;
            PropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

And then this:

```
MyClass.PropertyChanged += () =>
{
    DoSomethingWithNewValue(MyClass.Property);
};
```

For obvious reasons, this causes a deadlock.
What is the right way to handle this situation?

I can put PropertyChanged() after lock{}
or remove lock from get{}, or pass new value to the handler,
but it all looks somehow wrong.

Comment: Doesn't seem like _obvious reasons_ to me!

Comment: The `lock` won't help you at all because the side effects will be running on the same thread.

Are you really running into a deadlock or a stack overflow?

What is `DoSomethingWithNewValue` doing to `MyClass.Property`?

Comment: If I understand it correctly, the event raises inside lock block and then the code subscribed to that event tries to ackquire the lock again (through getter), causing it to wait forever.

Comment: Removing lock from getter or moving PropertyChanged() outside lock{} fixes it.

Comment: @user3360080: since you haven't posted the code, that reproduces the problem, it is hard to give you an answer. Post your real code.

Comment: Is your `PropertyChanged` handler method using `Dispatcher.Invoke`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dispatch the event after the lock, otherwise there can never be a guarantee that event handing code (which is out of your control) will not attempt to read the property and cause deadlock, even if you lock on a private object.

Comment: Reading the property value from the same thread, that raises an event, won't cause deadlock. The OP code sample doesn't tell us, that property being read from another thread.

Comment: I think I misunderstand the way locks work. Is it OK to lock again from inside the code called from the locked block?

Comment: It's ok for the same thread to re-enter the lock, so generally this shouldn't be an issue, however if there's other synchronisation code in your event handler, this sort of construct can cause very subtle bugs. There's no reason to dispatch change in the lock. I wouldn't.

Comment: @Gusdor: did you check that? ;)

Comment: @spender nope. It was always the way i undestood it. I assume it was trivial knowledge like _how big is an int32_ but alas, I was horribly horribly wrong. I have always been very careful to avoid the need for re-entrancy. Doesn't explain why this example is causing a deadlock though. The event handler is on the same thread as the initial locks.

Comment: @Gusdor: Yes... Locking is a hideous thing. My best advice is to reduce the scope of the lock to a minimum and to never, ever run code out of your control in the scope of the lock. I suspect that the event handling code actually has a call to `Dispatcher.Invoke` so that the UI can be manipulated. This is a blocking call that waits for its delegate to be run in the UI thread. Now we're in trouble. BOOM.

Comment: @spender boom indeed. Sounds like a nightmare :D

Comment: @spender Thanks! Turns out it is Control.Invoke that causes the hang.